# Final variable changing when it shouldn't be

Tags: java

Most of this code is from a template supplied by a lecturer.
Basically every time the Assert runs any function (for example the mult function) the second time, it uses the result returned from the first time the function was run instead of the original values of the array U[] which is supposed to be passed in.

The multiplication function:

```
`static double [] mult(double a, double [] V) { // multiplying scalar and vector
    double[] ans = V;
    //double [] ans = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
    for(int i =0; i<4; i++)
    {
        ans[i] = V[i]*a;
    }
    System.out.print("mult =" + ans[0] +" " + ans[1] +" " + ans[2] +" " + ans[3] + "\n");
    return ans;
}`
```

The main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    
    final double [] U = {1, 2, 3, 4}; 
    
    Assert(mult(2, U)[0] ==  2.0);  //returns U = 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0
    Assert(mult(2, U)[1] ==  4.0);  //returns U = 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 10.0 (should return same as above)
    Assert(mult(2, U)[2] ==  6.0); 
    Assert(mult(2, U)[3] ==  8.0);
```

Comment: `final` is not the same as `const` (which doesn’t exist in Java).  `final` only affects the declaration itself.  It is not recursive or “viral” and does not affect the contents of `U`, only the definition of `U` itself.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you assign `double[] ans = V;` instead of using a fresh array like this:

```java
double[] ans = new double[V.length];
```

You unintentionally use the array you get as a parameter as result array, and later change the values (which is legal but false).

`final` only ever referes to the reference you declare, for instance:

```java
final int[] a = { 1, 2, 3 };
a[2] = 5;
```

is perfectly legal, you just can't:

```java
a = new int[]{ 3, 4, 5 }; // compile error due to final modifier on identifier a.
```